# Can the retry operator catch errors like the retryWhen operator in RxJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, retrywhen

Question is based off *Reactive Patterns with RxJS for Angular by Lamis Chebbi*. Chapter 5: Error Handling. In the section covering 'retrying strategies'. My problem stems from an example used in the book featuring the soon to be deprecated *retryWhen* operator.

Here's the relevant observable logic, provided through a dedicated service `observable.service.ts`

```
export class ObservableService {

  observable$ = from(['1', '2', '3', 'Hello', '100']);

}
```

Here is the relevant code in the consuming component `app.component.ts`

```
  ngOnInit() { 


    this.observableService.observable$.pipe(
      map((value) => { if (isNaN(value as any)) { throw new Error } else return parseInt(value); }),
      retryWhen((errors) => { return errors.pipe(delayWhen(() => timer(5000))); }),
    ).subscribe({
      next: (value) => console.log('Value emitted', value),
      error: (error) => console.log('Error: ', error),
      complete: () => console.log('Stream completed'),
    });

 
  }
}
```

And the output which repeats every 5 seconds indefinitely

```
Value emitted 1
Value emitted 2
Value emitted 3
```

From my understanding, it loops because `retryWhen` catches `map()`'s errors and uses them as its notifier's event stream; which upon emitting resubscribes `retryWhen` to the source observable. `map()` will always throw in this example.

This is fine. The problem is attempting to use `retry` similarly. RxJS recommends using this operator over `retryWhen` moving forward, and in doing so I run into issues. Namely, I'm not sure if `retry` catches errors the same way.

Here is my attempt at producing the same output using `retry` in place of `retryWhen` in the consuming component `app.component.ts`

```
  ngOnInit() { 


    this.observableService.observable$.pipe(
      map((value) => { if (isNaN(value as any)) { throw new Error } else return parseInt(value); }),
      retry({ delay: (error) => { return error.pipe(delayWhen(() => timer(5000))); } }),
    ).subscribe({
      next: (value) => console.log('Value emitted', value),
      error: (error) => console.log('Coming from observer error handling function: ', error),
      complete: () => console.log('Stream completed'),
    }); 


  }
```

Which produces

```
Value emitted 1
Value emitted 2
Value emitted 3
Coming from observer error handling function:  TypeError: error.pipe is not a function
    at delay (app.component.ts:22:48)
    at retry.js:42:99
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (OperatorSubscriber.js:23:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:18)
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:16:33)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at Observable._subscribe (innerFrom.js:51:24)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:37:25)
    at Observable.js:31:30
    at errorContext (errorContext.js:19:9)
```

My goal is to reproduce the output shown in the book. Insight on getting the `retry` logic's output to loop indefinitely would be appreciated. Background on what's going on behind the scenes would be a nice-to-have. My leading assumption is `retry`'s not receiving `map()`'s errors. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Easy answer:

Use

```ts
retry({ delay: 5000 }),
```

Here's the doc on the [RetryConfig](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/RetryConfig)

#### retryWhen

retryWhen is passed a lambda whose parameter is observable stream of errors. This reifies errors as observable events, which is pretty much never useful and became a source of confusion unto itself. Pretty much no other operator works this way, though it's not too hard to get this behavior back.

#### Retry config

You can use RetryConfig's delay property to either set a delay in ms directly or you can return an observable time like before.

```ts
retry({ delay: _ => timer(5000) }),
```

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies